# Get String from JNI (OpenCV putText) to display in Java

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm building an app that measures the distance between colored circles. I am able to do that but I want to save the measurement data ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYPbM.jpg)) into a database (table in a new activity) that I am creating on Android but I don't know how to get the drawn String from the JNI to the activity that I'm creating for the database.

```
//put text
putText(mBgra, format("blue-green distance: %.2f cm ",conv3), Point(50,200), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, Scalar(0 , 255 , 0 , 255), 4);
```

How do I get the string from the code above and display it into a new java activity?

Comment: Do you have any code? This is a QA site, you didn't even ask your question. Did you expect us to write this for you?

Comment: @AustinWBryan I already edited my post.

Comment: putText() will produce a bitmap, you can display this bitmap in Android. Alternatively, you can use JNI to update some text field in your activity. The latter approach is often preferable.

Comment: @AlexCohn sir, can you provide an example on how to do the latter? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how to [pass the value into a textview on your activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577935/get-string-from-jni-opencv-puttext-to-display-in-java/34610127?noredirect=1#comment57502318_34610127).

I assume that in

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_alexies_objecttrackertest_UBackTrackViewer_UBackObjectTrack (JNIEnv * env , jobject ubackObject,
    jint width , jint height, jbyteArray yuv, jintArray bgra, jboolean debug)
```

**UBackTrackViewer ubackObject** is the activity you are asking about, and it defines the fields

```
private TextView mBlueGreenDistance, mBlueYellowDistance, mMagentaRedDistance;
```

You will probably initialize these fields to point to the actual text views in `onCreate()`, after you load the layout for your activity.

Then in your JNI code you will have this initialization sequence (it's enough to run it once after the textview fields are initialized):

```
jclass UBackTrackViewer_CLS = env->FindClass("com/example/alexies/objecttrackertest/UBackTrackViewer");
jclass TextView_CLS = env->FindClass("android/widget/TextView");
jmethodID setText_MID = env->GetMethodID(TextView_CLS, "setText", "(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V");

jfieldID mBlueGreenDistance_FID = env->GetFieldID(UBackTrackViewer_CLS, "mBlueGreenDistance", "Landroid/widget/TextView;");
…
```

Now, empowered by these globals, you can add the following to your native method:

```
jobject mBlueGreenDistance_OBJ = env->GetObjectField(ubackObject, mBlueGreenDistance_FID);
jstring distance_STR = env->NewStringUTF(format("blue-green distance: %.2f cm", conv3).c_str());
env->CallVoidMethod(mBlueGreenDistance_OBJ, setText_MID, distance_STR);
```

No cleanup is necessary in this case. No memory or reference leaks will happen. Note that **setText()** method must be called from the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there is a Java class

```
class MyClass {
    public String mSomething;
}
```

You will create an object of **MyClass** and pass it to your native code as **jobject myClassObject**.

Then in your C++ code you can write

```
jclass myClass = env->GetObjectClass(myClassObject);
if (myClass != NULL) {
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(MyClass, "mSomething", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (fid != NULL) {
        jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF(format("blue-green distance: %.2f cm ",conv3).c_str());
        env->SetObjectField(myClassObject, fid, jstr);
    }
}
```

For performance, **fid** may be cached and reused. You will not need to get **myClass** if you know **fid** already.

Comment: i can't seem to make it work. i have this float "conv3" on the jni package:  
  
`JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_alexies_objecttrackertest_UBackTrackViewer_UBackObjectTrack (JNIEnv * env , jobject ubackObject, jint width , jint height, jbyteArray yuv, jintArray bgra, jboolean debug)`  
  
and i want to pass the value of that float into the java activity.

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: here is the whole code of my jni: [pastebin] (http://pastebin.com/LBmucuch). It finds and draws blue and yellow circle patterns in an image frame and measures the distance between them. I want to pass the value of the distance to my android activity class which i will be using for database.

Comment: where should the distance go? To a float field (indexed by *i* 0…circles->total-1) of **ubackObject**? Or to a String field of this object? Or you can simply return an array of floats (or Strings) from your function.

Comment: I want to pass the value of it into a textview on my activity.